# JSTL enum labels

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I'm building web application in Spring and want to display enum value as a label in *.jsp

My enum:

```
public enum Type {BODY_WEIGHT, WEIGHTS};
```

Right now I'm displaying it in form using:

```
            <form:select path="type" items="${typeLabels}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="label">
               <form:options/>
            </form:select>
```

"typelabels" is a list of simple objects mapping enum value to a label:

```
    List<ExerciseType> typeLabels = new ArrayList<ExerciseType>();
    typeLabels.add(new ExerciseType(Type.BODY_WEIGHT, "Body weight"));
    typeLabels.add(new ExerciseType(Type.WEIGHTS, "With weights"));
```

Which works great.

Now I want to display list of objects with enum as a property:

```
          <c:forEach var="exercise" items="${list}" >
            <tr>
              <td>${exercise.title}</td>
              <td>${exercise.description}</td>
              <td>${exercise.type}</td>
            </tr>
          </c:forEach>
```

Obviously right now I'm getting values like 'BODY_WEIGHT' and 'WEIGHTS'.

Is there a way to supply list of mappings between enum values and their labels similar to previous example?

I don't want to hardcode labels in enums with something like BODY_WEIGHT("Body weight") since I want to localize application later.

Thanks!

Leo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associate a resource bundle to your enum, containing the enum names as keys, and the enum labels as values. Then use `<fmt:setBundle/>` and `<fmt:message>` with the enum name as a key to display the associated label:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.foo.bar.resources.Type" var="typeBundle"/>
<fmt:message key="${exercise.type}" bundle="${typeBundle}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!
I used <spring:message> tag since I already have localization bundle loaded but the idea behind this is the same.

I also changed the way I display option list - I found very nice custom tag to do just this - using the same message bundle:
http://www.springjutsu.org/2011/03/binding-enums-with-i8n-localization-support/

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum UserType {
ADMIN("Admin"), USER("User"), TEACHER("Teacher"), STUDENT("Student");

private String code;

UserType(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}


public static UserType fromCode(String userType) {
    for (UserType uType : UserType.values()) {
        if (uType.getCode().equals(userType)) {
            return uType;
        }
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The code " + userType + " is not supported!");
}
```

}

**In controller you need to set model as below:**

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/home/index");
```

model.addObject("user", new User());
model.addObject("types", UserType.values());

**In JSP you can get it as below:**

```
<form:select path="userType">
        <form:option value="" label="Chose Type" />
        <form:options items="${types}" itemLabel="code"  />
    </form:select>
```